# When using a DVCS in front of Subversion should I merge or rebase before pushing?

Tags: git, svn, mercurial, workflow, dvcs

My company uses Subversion officially, but I'm using Mercurial with the hgsubversion plugin for my daily work.

I tend to have more than one local feature branch (hg bookmark) going at a time. When I complete work on a branch I'll rebase it to the tip of the Subversion trunk and push the whole branch history into the Subversion repository.

I like that all of my granular changes get into the main repository - my coworkers can see why I make a change and not just the end result. But pushing to Subversion rewrites my commits, changing the timestamps to the moment of push, so I'm losing a little bit of fidelity from my work history.

I'm beginning to wonder if I should just be merging my local branches for the push to SVN and maintain my local commit history in branches in my Hg repository. If I move to a merge-oriented workflow, am I hurting my team? Is it realistically possible to sum up the changes that went into a merge with a single commit message?

Does Git->Subversion have this same sort of dichotomy? Aside from this philosophical issue, I'm quite happy with the Hg->Subversion workflow. But any Git users I've talked to seem to abhor the idea of using Git as a frontend for SVN for anything more than brief checkouts and patch submissions to open source projects.